# Getting req.param undefined in router

Tags: node.js, express

`req.params.id` is showing undefined inside the router. I have created one route for `comments`. You can see below code which I have wrote in app.js file. I am able to successfully navigate to the `/campgrounds/:id/comments` routes. But `req.params.id` is giving me undefined. you can see below images for reference

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let commentRoutes = require("./routes/comments");
...
app.use("/campgrounds", campgroundRoutes);
app.use("/campgrounds/:id/comments", commentRoutes);
```

[image]

Any configuration do I need to add?

```
let express = require("express");
let router  = express.Router();
router.get("/new", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  //find campground by Id
  console.log("req.params.id => "+ req.params.id);
  console.log("===========================");
  console.log("req.originalUrl => "+ req.originalUrl);
res.send("comments new");
});
```

[image]

Also, If I use `app.use(commentRoutes);` instead of `app.use("/campgrounds/:id/comments", commentRoutes);` it works, but with routes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you guys are facing same issue then you need to add `mergeParams` inside your child router if you want to access the params from the parent router.

```
var express = require("express");
var router  = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
```